# How do I know if GY-521 MPU6050 has been calibrated properly?

Tags: arduino-uno, mpu6050

I am planning to use the accelerometer of MPU6050 for a project.

I know that before using module (I am using GY-521 MPU6050), one needs to calibrate it.

I am using code by Luis Rodenas for calibration: https://sites.google.com/view/autoaero/code/auto-calibration-mpu6050

This code returns following offsets for my module:

```
-1123 -4100 1562 111 8 -1
```

Offsets are in Ax,Ay,Az,Gx,Gy,Gz format.
I am using these offsets in MPU6050_raw.ino example of i2cdevlib after making necessary adjustments. Here is the sketch

```
    // I2C device class (I2Cdev) demonstration Arduino sketch for MPU6050 class
// 10/7/2011 by Jeff Rowberg <jeff@rowberg.net>
// Updates should (hopefully) always be available at https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib
//


// I2Cdev and MPU6050 must be installed as libraries, or else the .cpp/.h files
// for both classes must be in the include path of your project
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"

// Arduino Wire library is required if I2Cdev I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE implementation
// is used in I2Cdev.h
#if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
    #include "Wire.h"
#endif

// class default I2C address is 0x68
// specific I2C addresses may be passed as a parameter here
// AD0 low = 0x68 (default for InvenSense evaluation board)
// AD0 high = 0x69
MPU6050 accelgyro;
//MPU6050 accelgyro(0x69); // <-- use for AD0 high

int16_t ax, ay, az;
int16_t gx, gy, gz;



// uncomment "OUTPUT_READABLE_ACCELGYRO" if you want to see a tab-separated
// list of the accel X/Y/Z and then gyro X/Y/Z values in decimal. Easy to read,
// not so easy to parse, and slow(er) over UART.
#define OUTPUT_READABLE_ACCELGYRO

// uncomment "OUTPUT_BINARY_ACCELGYRO" to send all 6 axes of data as 16-bit
// binary, one right after the other. This is very fast (as fast as possible
// without compression or data loss), and easy to parse, but impossible to read
// for a human.
//#define OUTPUT_BINARY_ACCELGYRO


#define LED_PIN 13
bool blinkState = false;

void setup() {
    // join I2C bus (I2Cdev library doesn't do this automatically)
    #if I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_ARDUINO_WIRE
        Wire.begin();
    #elif I2CDEV_IMPLEMENTATION == I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE
        Fastwire::setup(400, true);
    #endif

    // initialize serial communication
    // (38400 chosen because it works as well at 8MHz as it does at 16MHz, but
    // it's really up to you depending on your project)
    Serial.begin(115200);

    // initialize device
    Serial.println("Initializing I2C devices...");
    accelgyro.initialize();
    accelgyro.setFullScaleAccelRange(3);
    // verify connection
    Serial.println("Testing device connections...");
    Serial.println(accelgyro.testConnection() ? "MPU6050 connection successful" : "MPU6050 connection failed");

    // use the code below to change accel/gyro offset values

    Serial.println("Updating internal sensor offsets...");
    // -76 -2359 1688 0 0 0
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getXAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // -76
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getYAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // -2359
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getZAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 1688
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getXGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getYGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getZGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print("\n");
    accelgyro.setXGyroOffset(111);
    accelgyro.setYGyroOffset(8);
    accelgyro.setZGyroOffset(-1);
    accelgyro.setZAccelOffset(1562);
    accelgyro.setXAccelOffset(-1123);
    accelgyro.setYAccelOffset(-4100);
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getXAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // -76
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getYAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // -2359
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getZAccelOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 1688
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getXGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getYGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print(accelgyro.getZGyroOffset()); Serial.print("\t"); // 0
    Serial.print("\n");

    // configure Arduino LED pin for output
    pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // read raw accel/gyro measurements from device
    accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);

    // these methods (and a few others) are also available
    //accelgyro.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);
    //accelgyro.getRotation(&gx, &gy, &gz);

    #ifdef OUTPUT_READABLE_ACCELGYRO
        // display tab-separated accel/gyro x/y/z values
        Serial.print("a/g:\t");
        Serial.print(ax); Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(ay); Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(az); Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(gx); Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.print(gy); Serial.print("\t");
        Serial.println(gz);
    #endif

    #ifdef OUTPUT_BINARY_ACCELGYRO
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(ax >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(ax & 0xFF));
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(ay >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(ay & 0xFF));
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(az >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(az & 0xFF));
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(gx >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gx & 0xFF));
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(gy >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gy & 0xFF));
        Serial.write((uint8_t)(gz >> 8)); Serial.write((uint8_t)(gz & 0xFF));
    #endif

    // blink LED to indicate activity
    blinkState = !blinkState;
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, blinkState);
}
```

This is the output at serial monitor when module is horizontal with package letters facing up.
So have I calibrated the accelerometer properly? Please help if you can see any anomaly.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

consider looking at your acceleration and gyroscope data. if you have the device perfectly flat on the table you will find the gravitational force in some axis. tilt the whole setup and check if the g force now shows up in a different axis (hopefully the one you expect) then rotate the setup by 90 degrees around any axis. (always one at a time please!) if your gyro tells you that your rotational velocity per some measure of time roughly equals pi you know that everything works as expected. this actually works for every accelerometer and gyro so also these that you find on say the sparkfun 9dof board if you should ever come across those.

your cal can be tested by comparing a non cal-ed measurement with a cal-ed one. the differences between the expected value and the measured one should get smaller then.